# Corrupt EXT4 filesystem, backup superblock no dice

Tags: filesystems, inode, superblock

I am a novice linux user, for some time. I need some help with recovering a corrupted EXT4 filesystem.

Ideally, I would like to recover the filesystem intact. The drive in question is 'sda'. The partition structure is given below. I have tried to mount partition 1, with backup superblock, but no dice. No idea on how to proceed from here.

I am only attempting to fix 'sda1' now, as I will replicate what works on other partitions and drives. I have another 4Tb drive with the same issue. Thank you for your time.

**Context**: I was using a Live USB to read/write to 'sda'. I was using it for a while, in this situation, when one day the drive was no longer accessible. I tried acessing from a proper installation of linux from a hdd, and now here we area. The drive 'sdb' is current linux installation drive.

[image: Disks]

[image: Gparted]

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aujv1.png)

[image]

[image]

[Update] Remembered something. I had booted the disk from a test live cd and changed the permissions for all folders to rw across the 3 groups. Later, the drives were mounted(or tried to be mounted) on the original linux installation, with its own set of user & group rw permissions.
I think, the lack of the correct permissions that it had expected to see of the files & folders, corrupted the superblocks.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: Can you do a non-destructive `badblocks` check on the drive. Seems it's already got 896 known bad sectors - I just wonder if the drive is kaput - being an old spinning rust Seagate Barracuda, I'd say it's likely to be dead

Comment: @JaromandaX Will try it

Comment: Will edit the post with code, replacing the images.

Comment: if the drive health is in question, `ddrescue` it directly instead of anything else. you can't fix anything on a bad drive and having a copy is good practice for anything data recovery related, anyway (on an intact drive you could use snapshots / copy-on-write overlays instead)

Comment: for the mount failures, is there anything useful in journalctl/syslog/dmesg/...? mount only gives a generic message, kernel message might say what it didn't like in particular. if there are I/O errors they would also show up there.

Comment: @frostschutz : Could you point out how to do so ? It would help.